# Alpine linux on AWS / EC2 : how to login with my public key?

Tags: amazon-ec2, alpine

I'm trying to install Alpine Linux (v.3.6) on Amazon AWS EC2 via a standard community AMI. I provided my valid ssh key, which does work with all other instances (Amazon Linux) in the same VPC. However, I can't login to the instance. What is the default username for Alpine AWS?

Should my public SSH key be uploaded automatically into the instance like in case of Amazon Linux, Ubuntu, etc. - or is Alpine Linux AMI for some special installations only, so I should use Packer or smth. to create a new user and put my public key there?

Where can I find any documentation about AWS Alpine Comunity AMI?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If anyone's still scratching their heads on this one:

I just launched the latest `Alpine-3.7-r2-Hardened-EC2` instance with

```
ssh -i .ssh/KEY.pem alpine@host
```

Just guessed it followed the ubuntu@host pattern of the ubuntu instances.

Comment: how'd you manage to do it? it seems nothing is listening there: ssh: connect to host x.x.x.x port 22: Operation timed out. I tried `root` and `alpine`, neither worked

Comment: never mind, figured it out, it was configuration - I created another and yes, it works. would help if they had it documented somewhere :/

Comment: using the `Alpine-3.7-r2-Hardened-EC2` AMI you can become `root` with `sudo -s` after logging in as `alpine`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see the community AMI (ami-23475747) is undocumented.  The standard installation uses root and no password for login.  I have tested the AMI with my public key loaded and the server rejects the key.

Comment: I can't login via ssh into the server as a root user without a password.

Answer (score 0):

**If you're using PuTTY on Windows, upgrade to version 0.76 or newer.**

I ran into this same problem when trying to connect using PuTTY and Pageant 0.73 on Windows. I knew my key worked, since I had just used it for several other test machines. Per the other solutions on this post, I tried connecting on the command line using the `ssh` binary and manually specifying my SSH key as a `.pem` file, which curiously worked correctly. I assume this is because this version of SSH had installed had been updated more recently. This led me to try an upgrade of PuTTY, which connected properly immediately.